# Can artificers design new infusions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, artificer

Artificers in 3.5 cast infusions, this is neither arcane nor divine. Yet they create magical effects. Artificers gain infusions just like a spell caster, and cast infusions in a manner just like sorcerers do.

Knowing this information wouldn't it follow logically that artificers, like spellcasters, can create new spells in much the same way?

Answer (score 7):

Infusions are spells, and there are suggestions that new spells can be designed. Those suggestions were printed in Core, and not reprinted for each new spellcasting class (including artificer) was printed, but if, say, a favored soul or wu jen can research a new spell, then so too should an artificer be able to.

Of course, the real trick is convincing the DM that any particular invented spell is a good inclusion to the game. In practice, the suggestions that spellcasters can design new spells are rarely actually used—in most games, the DM is the arbiter of the allowed material, and the existence of that suggestion means nothing. If a player wants to add something to the game, no matter what it is, they can bring it up with the DM, but the DM is going to choose and usually won’t take the existence or absence of a statement like what you see for spells into consideration.

Comment: Good to know. My DM is a big fan of customization and while he of course wouldn't allow an artificer to create so many spells he's basically a wizard he quit be fine with new spells of similar but alternative designs from the artificers infusion list. I think we both agree that if you're trying to turn an artificer into a wizard it would be cheaper to be a crafting wizard

Comment: @Zakier You have asked a couple of questions about these kinds of customization/research blurbs. They’re *basically meaningless and no one pays them any attention.* The people sitting around the table can customize the game any way they agree to (and, of course, the DM has a lot more “vote” since he’ll have to be the one running things under the new rules). What the books do or don’t say about any given customization should be taken as a suggestion *if even that.*

Comment: Do you have a reference for that "Infusions are spells" thing?

Comment: @GMJoe “[Infusions] function just like spells and follow all the rules for spells,” *Eberron Campaign Setting* pg. 31.

Comment: Of course final decision is his to make. But if by raw something simply can't be done then why bother trying? Not to mention I can't exactly ask the dm currently. He was in a car accident so I'm not going to bother him with rules clarification. Along side that I co GM with him and this is a new class for both of us. Neither of us know it's capabilities

Comment: @Zakier Well, that’s my point: by RAW, there is *nothing* that a given table is not allowed to customize. All of it is open for changes. This is codified in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* as “rule 0.” Regardless of whether or not a specific mention of such customization possibilities is made in the rules. Nothing suggests people can research new feats like spellcasters can research new spells; that doesn’t mean a group isn’t allowed to decide to add new feats—the rules explicitly state you can change that, along with everything else.

Comment: @Zakier Now, if the concern is that a new or unfamiliar class may present unique problems when adding new features, that is a different question than the one you asked, and a much more interesting one. For instance, the artificer automatically knows every infusion there is, rather than having to pick infusions known as a sorcerer does spells. Beguiler, dread necromancer, and warmage are similar with their spell lists, and as a result, *Spell Compendium* recommends against adding too much to those spell lists. Is the artificer the same? Valid question.

Comment: Very good point, though researching more specifically has yielded that under infusions it specifically says artificers are NOT spellcasters but at the same time they CAN learn new infusions. They automatically gain all available infusions so the only way they could learn new ones "from finding them in the wastes" would be if they where created. By the dm. Which should mean the artificer could research new ones.

Comment: If all else fails though, have a wizard create a spell then create Scrolls or schema.

Comment: @KRyan That quote is an important reference - you should edit it in to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in Magic of Ebberon page 10

> LEARNING NEW INFUSIONS
>   Infusions are neither arcane nor divine, but these spell-like rites are central to artifi ce magic. Using infusions, an artifi cer can imbue an item or construct with special qualities and abilities. Many artificers throughout Eberron have continued to evolve their infusions. They might create entirely new infusions or find an ancient schema with instructions on a new magical technique. The infusions in this book represent a small portion of the widely varying infusions in use.